# Why did the maiden flight of H3 fail?

Tags: rockets, launch, failure, jaxa, ignition

Recently, JAXA (Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency) finally [launched](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RWCnKbysO0) the ALOS-3 (Advanced Land Observing Satellite-3) after more than 2 years of delay. On then all seemed to be going well on the first stage, and it appears to have separeted clearly. Then the little animation shows it firing, but the velocity continues decreasing at its normal rate. They eventually activated the So what happened here. I would assume that there was some issue with second stage ignition. What happened and why?
NOTE:Stage seperation is at 1:04:35

Comment: It might be a bit too early to answer this question. Incident investigations take at least weeks, typically months, sometimes years. Just a few examples: Virgin Orbit's failure on January 9th and New Shepard's failure on September 13th still remain under investigation after 62 and 180 days. The two results published in the last days, Astra LV0010 and ArianeSpace Vega-C took 262 and 73 days. SpaceX AMOS-6 and CRS-7 took 4 and 33(!!!) months. The Space Shuttle Challenger and Columbia investigations took 4.5 and almost 7 months (and the Crew Survivability Report for Columbia 5 years).

Comment: Okay. Still a good question such as this"space.stackexchange.com/questions/61532/… eventually got answerable @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit premature to ask why a launch vehicle failed just a few days after the failure occurred. In this case, the second stage engine apparently failed to ignite. What caused that failure may not be known for several weeks, if not longer. JAXA and Mitsubishi Heavy Industries will be pouring over the telemetry to find the root cause (or maybe root causes) of the failure -- and then develop a fix. Finding the root cause will take some time. Finding a solution will take even more time.

Comment: Not really answering the question @David Hammen

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch That the second stage failed to ignite is the only answer to your question, at least for now. This often happens with questions asked by newcomers to space exploration who want detailed answers **now** regarding failures. There typically are no detailed answers until weeks or even months after the failure occurred.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch - this answer is all that can be provided at this stage. It may be that your question would be better closed until answers are possiible

Comment: Perhaps not closed but yes I agree maybe time is needed. @RoryAlsop

Comment: A reasonable question has attracted a lot of down-votes.

Comment: see https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/whats-best-to-do-about-questions-that-might-not-be-answerable-for-a-few-months

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance The question has two (2) downvotes, out of 34000+ users on this site. I wouldn't call that "a lot".

Comment: For 74 views, that is a lot. It is odd to see that bad of a reaction with so little views to reasonable posts. @Jo

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Perhaps you should take that as a sign that this is not a reasonable question. Note well: I am not one of the two downvoters. I'm not an upvoter, either. Also note well: I typically upvote questions that I answer, but not this time.

Comment: As in how was I supposed to know that it was answerable yet? @DavidHammen

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Asking for a detailed explanation of a failure just a few days after the failure occurred is almost always unanswerable, at least immediately. It's a bit of a rookie kind of question. (There's nothing wrong with that, per se; we all start as rookies.) JAXA does know the non-detailed answer, which is that the second stage failed to ignite. I suspect JAXA and MHI have dozens of people, and more likely hundreds of people, looking into this failure.

Comment: Okay I asked what happened to Firefly Alpha a few days after though and that went fine @DavidHammen